# Classroom API call for Add Student performace is slow

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-classroom

We are implementing a BatchRequest to send students to the API endpoint for [Students/Create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create).  We've set them up as follows:

Create the BatchRequest

```
var batch = new BatchRequest(service);
```

Then we create a CallBack Function:

```
BatchRequest.OnResponse<Student> callback = (studentResponse, error, i, message) =>
                    {
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            this.context.LogMessage($"Error Adding: Student '{student.StudentEmail} - {student.SectionKey} \r\n {message}'");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            studentLinksAdded.Add(studentResponse);

                            this.context.LogMessage($"Student '{student.StudentEmail}-{student.SectionKey}' was added.");
                        }
                    };
```

We then create a CreateRequest, the sectionkey used here is an Alias that was used when creating the course ("d:**alias key**")

```
Student toAdd = new Student()
{
    UserId = StudentEmail
};

CoursesResource.StudentsResource.CreateRequest studentCreate = service.Courses.Students.Create(toAdd, sectionKey);
```

Then Queue it:

```
batch.Queue<Student>(studentAddRequest, callback);
```

Finally do a check to see if we've hit 400 (magic number we found while creating courses was rate-limiting enough to avoid quote issues) or the total records (batch the rest of the requests) and fire the call to the API.

```
if (batch.Count % 400 == 0 || totalRecordToProcess == currentRecordProcessed)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        tasks.Add(batch.ExecuteAsync());
        tasks.Add(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.25)));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        i = 3;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(.5)));
}
```

The delay in the WaitAll for the batch was to agree not to send too many requests per minute (quota).  And the final WaitAll will delay between request a guaranteed 30 seconds for throttling.

Metrics for speed:

Batches of 400 have taken: 15.21, 15.48, 15.29 (minutes)

So if we have ~230k records of students to add to courses, this will complete in about 8 days.

Is there some way to speed this up?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be better off posting to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you are going to have to do some parallel processing here. You can either use .NET's parallel options or you can write an executable that accepts a set of classes and students and run multiple copies of it (parceling out the work), but there is no getting around the need to break it up.

Google can handle working on multiple classes at a time, and you can handle the processing and memory requirements. Since the latency is on the time spent doing network calls in sequence, you need a means of making many network calls simultaneously so that each set of calls can wait on itself.